# Errores al Crear BD SQL

Tags: mysql

Estoy usando MySQL Workbench para crear una BD y me da el siguiente error, aun soy nuevo en esto espero me puedan ayudar. El error es el siguiente:

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1005: Can't create table `bd_easymaker_0`.`equipos` (errno: 121 "Duplicate key on write or update")
SQL Code:


    -- -----------------------------------------------------
        -- Table `BD_EasyMaker_0`.`Equipos`
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `BD_EasyMaker_0`.`Equipos` (
          `ID_Equipo` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `ID_Proyecto` INT NOT NULL,
          `ID_Usuario1` INT NOT NULL,
          `ID_Usuario2` INT NOT NULL,
          `ID_Imagen` INT NULL,
          `ID_Usuario3` INT NULL,
          `ID_Usuario4` INT NULL,
          `ID_Usuario5` INT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`ID_Equipo`),
          INDEX `ID_Usuario1_idx` (`ID_Usuario1` ASC),
          INDEX `ID_Usuario2_idx` (`ID_Usuario2` ASC),
          INDEX `ID_Usuario3_idx` (`ID_Usuario3` ASC),
          INDEX `ID_Usuario4_idx` (`ID_Usuario4` ASC),
          INDEX `ID_Usuario5_idx` (`ID_Usuario5` ASC),
          INDEX `ID_Imagen_idx` (`ID_Imagen` ASC),
          INDEX `ID_Proyecto_idx` (`ID_Proyecto` ASC),
          CONSTRAINT `ID_Usuario1`
            FOREIGN KEY (`ID_Usuario1`)
            REFERENCES `BD_EasyMaker_0`.`Usuarios` (`ID_Usuario`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
          CONSTRAINT `ID_Usuario2`
            FOREIGN KEY (`ID_Usuario2`)
            REFERENCES `BD_EasyMaker_0`.`Usuarios` (`ID_Usuario`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
          CONSTRAINT `ID_Usuario3`
            FOREIGN KEY (`ID_Usuario3`)
            REFERENCES `BD_EasyMaker_0`.`Usuarios` (`ID_Usuario`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
          CONSTRAINT `ID_Usuario4`
            FOREIGN KEY (`ID_Usuario4`)
            REFERENCES `BD_EasyMaker_0`.`Usuarios` (`ID_Usuario`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
          CONSTRAINT `ID_Usuario5`
            FOREIGN KEY (`ID_Usuario5`)
            REFERENCES `BD_EasyMaker_0`.`Usuarios` (`ID_Usuario`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
          CONSTRAINT `ID_Imagen`
            FOREIGN KEY (`ID_Imagen`)
            REFERENCES `BD_EasyMaker_0`.`Imagenes` (`ID_Imagen`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
          CONSTRAINT `ID_Proyecto`
            FOREIGN KEY (`ID_Proyecto`)
            REFERENCES `BD_EasyMaker_0`.`Proyectos` (`ID_Proyectos`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
        ENGINE = InnoDB

SQL script execution finished: statements: 7 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

/// Dejo el original arriba para futuras referencias.

Ahora tengo menos errores pero no encuentro donde este el error en este fragmento:

```
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `BD_EasyMaker_0`.`Usuarios`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `BD_EasyMaker_0`.`Usuarios` (
      `ID_Usuario` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `Nombre` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `Ocupacion` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `Facultad` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `Universidad` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `Rank` INT NULL,
      `Habilidades` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `Sexo` INT NOT NULL,
      `Email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `Equipo` INT NULL,
      `Imagen` INT NOT NULL,
      `Contrasena` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`ID_Usuario`),
      INDEX `ID_Imagen_idx` (`Imagen` ASC),
      INDEX `ID_Equipo_idx` (`Equipo` ASC),
      CONSTRAINT `FK_ID_Equipo`
        FOREIGN KEY (`Equipo`)
        REFERENCES `BD_EasyMaker_0`.`Equipos` (`ID_Equipo`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
      CONSTRAINT `FK_ID_Imagen`
        FOREIGN KEY (`Imagen`)
        REFERENCES `BD_EasyMaker_0`.`Imagenes` (`ID_Imagen`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
```

SQL script execution finished: statements: 8 succeeded, 1 failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema esta en las llaves foraneas por el nombre, prueba cambiando los nombres de los constraints, este error suele suceder porque los constraints tienen el mismo identificador que las columnas

Los cambie agregando fk_ a cada constraint

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `BD_EasyMaker_0`.`Equipos` (
          `ID_Equipo` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `ID_Proyecto` INT NOT NULL,
          `ID_Usuario1` INT NOT NULL,
          `ID_Usuario2` INT NOT NULL,
          `ID_Imagen` INT NULL,
          `ID_Usuario3` INT NULL,
          `ID_Usuario4` INT NULL,
          `ID_Usuario5` INT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`ID_Equipo`),
          INDEX `ID_Usuario1_idx` (`ID_Usuario1` ASC),
          INDEX `ID_Usuario2_idx` (`ID_Usuario2` ASC),
          INDEX `ID_Usuario3_idx` (`ID_Usuario3` ASC),
          INDEX `ID_Usuario4_idx` (`ID_Usuario4` ASC),
          INDEX `ID_Usuario5_idx` (`ID_Usuario5` ASC),
          INDEX `ID_Imagen_idx` (`ID_Imagen` ASC),
          INDEX `ID_Proyecto_idx` (`ID_Proyecto` ASC),

          CONSTRAINT `fk_ID_Usuario1`
            FOREIGN KEY (`ID_Usuario1`)
            REFERENCES `BD_EasyMaker_0`.`Usuarios` (`ID_Usuario`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
          CONSTRAINT `fk_ID_Usuario2`
            FOREIGN KEY (`ID_Usuario2`)
            REFERENCES `BD_EasyMaker_0`.`Usuarios` (`ID_Usuario`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
          CONSTRAINT `fk_ID_Usuario3`
            FOREIGN KEY (`ID_Usuario3`)
            REFERENCES `BD_EasyMaker_0`.`Usuarios` (`ID_Usuario`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
          CONSTRAINT `fk_ID_Usuario4`
            FOREIGN KEY (`ID_Usuario4`)
            REFERENCES `BD_EasyMaker_0`.`Usuarios` (`ID_Usuario`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
          CONSTRAINT `fk_ID_Usuario5`
            FOREIGN KEY (`ID_Usuario5`)
            REFERENCES `BD_EasyMaker_0`.`Usuarios` (`ID_Usuario`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
          CONSTRAINT `fk_ID_Imagen`
            FOREIGN KEY (`ID_Imagen`)
            REFERENCES `BD_EasyMaker_0`.`Imagenes` (`ID_Imagen`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
          CONSTRAINT `fk_ID_Proyecto`
            FOREIGN KEY (`ID_Proyecto`)
            REFERENCES `BD_EasyMaker_0`.`Proyectos` (`ID_Proyectos`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
        ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Answer (score 0):

No se puede crear la tabla porque tus `CONSTRAINT` tienen el mismo nombre que tus columnas. Debes usar un identificador diferente para los `CONSTRAINT` por ejemplo fk_idUsuario1

```
CONSTRAINT `FK_ID_Usuario1`
            FOREIGN KEY (`ID_Usuario1`)
            REFERENCES `BD_EasyMaker_0`.`Usuarios` (`ID_Usuario`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
```